# Jupyter notebook stops running when screen locked (not sleep mode)

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, screen-lock

When I leave my script in Jupyter Notebook for a while, it apparently pauses running. The computer itself is not going to sleep mode (I made sure that I put "Never go to sleep on battery power"), but the screen locks. I use: Windows 10 on Microsoft Surface, Jupyter Notebook py36, Google Chrome as a default browser. What should I do to make the script running longer?

Thank you!